# wmode="opaque" in internet explorer 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, flash

wmode="opaque" for flash object works in chrome but not in IE9. when I open dialog window, flash video continues showing and is not dimming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have written this for Internet Explorer 9:

```
<object id="XwebcamXobjectX" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"... >
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
...
</object>
```

Instead Of:

```
<object id="XwebcamXobjectX" wmode="opaque" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"...
...
</object>
```